# Passing Variable from JS to VB.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a variable that gets a value in a js function. I need to get its value as a double into a vb.net variable.

I have tried putting the variable into a label then  grabbing it from the label in vb.net  as shown in the code below:

Js part.

```
document.getElementById("Label1").innerText = nwLat;
```

then in the vb part

```
   Dim nwLat As Double
    nwLat = Label1.Text
    MsgBox(nwLat)
```

it does not work for me any ideas? the error that comes up is
 Input string was not in a correct format.

Cheers!

Comment: What isn't working? Does the code throw an Exception? Is the value simply empty? We need more details...

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. is the error

Comment: is Label1 the actual id of the label in the HTML?

Comment: The label's text value will be maintained in and retrieved from ViewState, so this is unlikely to work. Try using an `<input type="hidden" />` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way without any type of ajax would be to use a hidden field.

Markup:

`<asp:HiddenField ID="nwLatHidden" runat="server" Value="" />`

JS:

`document.getElementById('nwLatHidden').value = '6.00'; // or of course the value from your function.`

.NET during your postback routine:

```
Dim nwLat As Double
nwLat = nwLatHidden.Value
```

Comment: it Errors with ~Input string was not in a correct format at nwLat = CDbl(nwLatHidden.value)

Comment: Do you know how to attach a debugger? What is the value of `nwLatHidden` before trying to cast it to a `double`?

Comment: See my edit above and check the result to see if it can be parsed into the double type.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript:

```
__doPostBack(
    'edit',
    JSON.stringify({ ID: id, Code: code, AcctNo: acctNo })
);
```

In VB.NET:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(s As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        '...
    Else
        Dim eventTarget As String = Request.Form!__EVENTTARGET
        Dim eventArgument As String = Request.Form!__EVENTARGUMENT
        If Not eventArgument Is Nothing AndAlso Not eventTarget Is Nothing AndAlso eventTarget = "edit" Then
            Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim ac As AccountCode = jss.Deserialize(Of AccountCode)(eventArgument)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ClientID or the UniqueID:

```
document.getElementById("<%=Label1.UniqueID%>").innerText = "Hi";
```